# How to calculate goodness of fitting (GOF) from a dataset in java?

Tags: java, statistics, apache-commons

What are the options to calculate goodness of fitting (GOF) from a dataset in java, i was looking at apache math 3.0 library and i could not get my head around the way to calculate GOF using it. Any suggestions for other libraries or for math 3.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For linear least squares it's usually the r coefficient.  r = 1.0 means a perfect fit; r = -1.0 means the equation is orthogonal to the data, r = 0.0 means no fit (thanks to Peter Lawrey for the correction).  Typical values are somewhere in between.

For higher order functions you should look at the confidence level calculated for each coefficient.

The best way to figure it out is visually: look at the data and the fit.

If "could not get my head around" is code for "I never knew the mathematics behind it in the first place", a change in library won't help.  Taking the time to read and understand the math will.

Comment: I usually use correlation in which case 1.0 (moved together) and -1.0 (moves opposite) are equaly good, and 0.0 means no fit at all.

Comment: im looking for java libraries that does the calculation from a dataset .. and i was wondering if math 3.0 or any other library does that

Comment: Yeah, I get it.  The problem is that no library is going to do your thinking for you.  It'll fit the function that you ask it to.  Knowing the data is all-important in making that choice.  Blindly expecting a library to do all the thinking is a poor decision.